# Create a list property in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, indexing, properties

I am starting OOP with Python 3 and I find the concept of `property` really interesting.

I need to encapsulate a private list, but how could I use this paradigm for lists?

Here's my naive try:

```
class Foo:
    """ Naive try to create a list property.. and obvious fail """

    def __init__(self, list):
        self._list = list

    def _get_list(self, i):
        print("Accessed element {}".format(i))
        return self._list[i]

    def _set_list(self, i, new):
        print("Set element {} to {}".format(i, new))
        self._list[i] = new

    list = property(_get_list, _set_list)
```

This doesn't behave as expected and even makes python crash when I try the following code. This is the fictive behavior I would like `Foo` to exhibit:

```
>>> f = Foo([1, 2, 3])
>>> f.list
[1, 2, 3]
>>> f.list[1]
Accessed element 1
2
>>> f.list[1] = 12
Set element 1 to 12
>>> f.list
[1, 12, 3]
```

Comment: Are the `print`s important?

Comment: @AnandSKumar Yes they are, since they actually represent further update to the other class members I perform using the value of both `i` and `new`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import collections


class PrivateList(collections.MutableSequence):
    def __init__(self, initial=None):
        self._list = initial or []

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self._list)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        print("Accessed element {}".format(item))
        return self._list[item]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print("Set element {} to {}".format(key, value))
        self._list[key] = value

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        print("Deleting element {}".format(key))
        del self._list[key]

    def __len__(self):
        print("Getting length")
        return len(self._list)

    def insert(self, index, item):
        print("Inserting item {} at {}".format(item, index))
        self._list.insert(index, item)


class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a_list):
        self.list = PrivateList(a_list)
```

Then runnning this:

```
foo = Foo([1,2,3])
print(foo.list)
print(foo.list[1])
foo.list[1] = 12
print(foo.list)
```

Outputs:

```
[1, 2, 3]
Accessed element 1
2
Set element 1 to 12
[1, 12, 3]
```

Comment: So I *was* needing a new class and overriding of the `[]` operators. Now this makes perfect sense. Thank you! ^ ^

Comment: yes, your code only checked for access to the `list` property, not any operations on the object returned by that property.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems in your code. They might not be the only problems but fixing them would bring you further:

- Properties are for new style classes. They are derived from `object`:

  `class Foo(object):`
- The getter (the first argument to `property` will be called without argument. So `_get_list` can't have the second argument `i`. The same applies to `_set_list` it can only have one argument, not two. (`self` is implicit and does not count here.)

Comment: Very true. This is why I called my try "naive" ;)